# PayPal IPN showing verify_sign=undefined

Tags: php, paypal-ipn

I am testing PayPal IPN Simulator.
It is always showing `INVALID` and `verify_sign=undefined`

I have all the prerequisites needed such as `ssl with 2048 key`, I have put `IPN Listener url` and `Return url` Properly in my PayPal account.

I am testing this way.

```
http_response_code(200);
$ch = curl_init();
$req="cmd=_notify-validate&".http_build_query($_POST);
$req=utf8_encode($req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$ch_error=curl_error($ch);

$log=$req.'<br><br>';
$log.=$response.'<br><br>';
$log.=$ch_error;
file_put_contents("ipn.txt", $log);
```

I am getting response as below with `date` field set as `NULL`, All fields are in exact same order as in IPN Simulator, However field `test_ipn=1 and verify_sign=undefined` are not shown in IPN Simulator.

```
cmd=_notify-validate
payment_type=instant
payment_date=NULL
payment_status=Completed
address_status=confirmed
payer_status=verified
first_name=John
last_name=Smith
payer_email=buyer%40paypalsandbox.com
payer_id=TESTBUYERID01
address_name=John+Smith
address_country=United+States
address_country_code=US
address_zip=95131
address_state=CA
address_city=San+Jose
address_street=123+any+street
business=seller%40paypalsandbox.com
receiver_email=seller%40paypalsandbox.com
receiver_id=seller%40paypalsandbox.com
residence_country=US
item_name=something
item_number=AK-1234
quantity=1
shipping=3.04
tax=2.02
mc_currency=USD
mc_fee=0.44
mc_gross=12.34
mc_gross_1=9.34
txn_type=web_accept
txn_id=203725327¬ify_version=2.1
custom=xyz123
invoice=abc1234
test_ipn=1
verify_sign=undefined
```

And Paypal returns

```
INVALID
```

I have contacted PayPal support but got no answer yet.

Please see if the issue is from my end and suggest a way to resolve it.
Thanks

Comment: Make sure your ipn validate is correct, Try this: https://github.com/jagjeet1991/paypal_ipn

Comment: Using your suggested library and other like [This](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples) shows same error `INVALID` and `verify_sign=undefined`

Comment: @TallboY I have the same issue with the Python one, were you able to solved it ?